# ¿Como Mostrar los últimos 14 registros de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito Mostrar los últimos 14 registros de una de mis tablas Utilizando SQL, ¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo? En algunos foros mostraba que usaban la etiqueta **TOP** pero en **phpmyadmin** no lo reconoce. Si agrego la etiqueta **LIMIT** me muestra solo los primeros 14

```
SELECT hrs_ini, hrs_ter, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, 
fecha_registro
FROM horario
INNER JOIN usuarios ON horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu
WHERE fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario)
```

En las Respuestas, me mencionar que lo ejecutara de la siguiente forma

```
 SELECT  hrs_ini, hrs_ter, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado,fecha_registro
 FROM horario
 INNER JOIN usuarios ON horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu
 WHERE fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario) 
 ORDER BY id_hr DESC LIMIT 14
```

El resultado de esto es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo a pesar de que se muestran los últimos 14 registros  el orden de las Horas no es el correcto. Pero si Quito el  DESC, No me muestra los últimos 14 registros, sino que los primeros 14

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: El horario de los primeros 14 registros no se atiende a estudiantes los días jueves, en los últimos 14 registro si se atienden a estudiantes los días jueves, ese es el cambio que hice en el horario para diferenciarlos. Gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: depende del motor de base de datos que estás usando. Cuál es?

Comment: Estoy usando phpmyadmin que utiliza Mysql

Comment: Prueba a ordenar de manera descendente y con un Limit 14

Comment: y con qué columna revisas el orden de los datos?

Comment: El orden? de momento  con ninguna, ya que están en el orden que quiero, aunque podría ser con la clave primaria id_hr. Aunque si le agrego esta linea me da error ORDER BY id_hr DESC

Comment: @derloopkat no debería afectar el no tener el id en el select

Comment: @OP: Incluye el SQL a tu pregunta donde intentas con el `ORDER BY` y el `LIMIT`, e incluye el error que recibes.

Comment: Era  por el orden de los factores creo, si agrego Order By primero no hay error alguno

Comment: Voy a agregar el resultado de una de las respuestas para que se entienda, denme un minuto, gracias por responder.

Comment: creo que el problema es que tienes que ordenar por fecha y por hora de manera desc y limit 14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con order y Limit

```
select * from (
    SELECT id_hr, hrs_ini, hrs_ter, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, 
    fecha_registro
    FROM horario
    INNER JOIN usuarios ON horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu
    WHERE fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario) ORDER BY id_hr DESC LIMIT 14
) tmp order by tmp.id_hr asc
```

id_hr debe ser tu llave incremental así obtendrías los últimos insertado, y los re ordenarías.

Comment: Me sigue sin mostrar los últimos, de todas formas gracias por responder

Comment: @CristianOx21 usaste el primer código cambiando `idKey` por tu `id_hr`?

Comment: si lo hice, lo cambien por id_hr, Ahora bien si hago eso me muestra los últimos 14 registros,  sin embargo no lo hace como debería, ya que muestra las ultimas horas como las primeras, y si quito el  DESC  no me muestra los ultimos 14 sino los primeros 14 XD

Comment: Voy a Editar la pregunta Y mostrare el resultado de tu respuesta para que se entienda.

Comment: `ya que muestra las ultimas horas como las primeras` <- bueno, claro, porque estás ordenando por el `id_hr` descendente. Realmente necesitas que el resultado entregado por el motor de bases de datos sea en ese orden particular?, no basta con que te entregue los 14 que buscas y tú lo muestres como quieras en tu aplicación?

Comment: agrego algo para re-ordenar entonces...

Comment: @Francisco: ojo que el segundo `ORDER BY` sí necesita que la columna esté presente en el `SELECT` interior.

Comment: @sstan no lo creo por que el select interior es para traer la fecha máxima registrada osea si el ultimo registro fue en el 2016, su fecha máxima corresponderá a la fecha del registro del 2016 para abajo... y el inner es para hacerlo por cada empleado.

Comment: a lo que se refiere @sstan es que ahora lanzará error, porque ya no hay un `id_hr` en tu tabla derivada

Comment: @Lamak claro tendrá que agregar el Id tambien a la consulta.

Comment: Ademas para mejorar la respuesta tendria que indicar que espera obtener...

Comment: Si, con eso no hay problema de agregar al id, solo no lo muestro en mi resultado de mi aplicación, muchas gracias funciono perfecto :D

Answer (score 2):

Ordena por el id y quédate los primeros 14

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 14
```